# Converting binary stored in 2 unsigned character to integer

Tags: c, binary, char

If I have two variables:

```
unsigned char var1, var2;
var1 = 4A; // for simplicity I am showing the hex value 4A, but it is 1 
            // byte of binary representing the value 4A - 0100 1010
var2 = 3F;
```

I want to return from the function the integer result given by: 3F4A

In C could I simply do this?

```
int result;
var2 << 8;   // left shift var2 by 8 bits
result = var1 + var2;
return result;
```

Can I simply "cast" the binary stored in the char variables to int in this manner? I.e would result return the integer 16202?

Comment: 16202 = 0x3F4A anyways, what do you want to cast exactly?

Comment: @Anton.P Given that I have 4A stored in var1 and 3F stored in var2, I want to return the integer value of 0x3F4A

Comment: unsigned int result=(((unsigned int)var2<<8) | var1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although on most platforms it will work to use signed arithmetic, to be pedantically formally correct you should use *unsigned* types for the computation of the bit pattern.

Now, first of all

```
var2 << 8;
```

does not left shift `var2`: it's just an expression computing a result, that's discarded.

That result is of signed type `int`, because `int` is the highest common type of the operands.

You want an `unsigned` computation, so make sure at least one operand is of unsigned type, i.e.

```
return static_cast<int>( var1 + (var2 << 8u) );
```

To be entirely bit-level-ish, replace the `+` with bitlevel OR, `|`. But it does not matter logically, and most likely the same machine code is generated.

Comment: In my code I did have it as `var2 = var2 << 8;` My char variables are unsigned, that is not what you are referring to?

Comment: @user3501476: Your `unsigned char` variables are OK. Regarding your code, I'm not telepathic, there's no way I could see that code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using some nasty bit level hacking like this:

```
result = (int) ( ((int)var2) << 8 | var1 )
```

I am not sure whether the bitshift would overflow var2, so cast it to int first, shift it 8 places to the left, and then preform the binary OR with var1.

Comment: The inner cast performs no function. But its intention (which is the same as happens anyway) is to use a formally unsuitable result type.

Answer (score 0):

this line: 'var2 << 8; ' will fail

(should be caught by the compiler,.

another good reason to always compile with all warnings enabled)

because var2 is only 8 bits wide.

suggest a third variable to hold the result:

```
int var3;  
var3 = (int)var2;  
var3 <<=8;  
var3 |= (int)var1;
```

the above is in simple steps, many of the steps could be combined.